# Creating a SVN repository with a java method

Tags: eclipse, svnkit

I'm working on a spring boot project and I need to build a method that can create a SVN repository to the svnserver.
I found the **SVNKit** library so I installed the Subclipse from the marketplace in Eclipse but when I do the imports it can't resolve them.

**Here is the solution I found**

```
   2 import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNURL;
   3 import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException;
   4 ...
   5 
   6     try {
   7         String tgtPath = "C:/repos/root/path";
   8         SVNURL tgtURL = SVNRepositoryFactory.createLocalRepository( new File( tgtPath ), true , false );
   9     } catch ( SVNException e ) {
  10         //handle exception
  11     }
```

Any idea please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to add svnkit dependency in your pom.xml, try adding this do your projects pom.xml and run a clean, your imports should get resolved:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</groupId>
    <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```